# How do I stop else in if/else from being executed?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, contains

I am using a scanner method for the user to input one of the words in the string, but the else is still being executed even if the user inputs one of the strings. How do I prevent that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {         
    while(true) {
        StringBuffer StringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi, what are you trying to find?");
        System.out.println("mass");
        System.out.println("vol");
        System.out.println("temp");
        System.out.println("sphere");
        System.out.println("density");
        String convert = input.nextLine();
        if (String.valueOf(convert).contains("mass, volume, sphere, temp, density, pound, ounce, ton, gram,")) { 
            StringBuffer.append(String.valueOf(convert));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need the String.valueOf(convert), just do convert.

Answer (score 1):

The other way around, call `contains` on your string of variants. And as [Clone Talk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987669/clone-talk) mentioned you don't need `String.valueOf`, since `convert` is already a `String`(Though, it works with it as well.) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        StringBuffer StringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi, what are you trying to find?");
        System.out.println("mass");
        System.out.println("vol");
        System.out.println("temp");
        System.out.println("sphere");
        System.out.println("density");
        String convert = input.nextLine();
        if ("mass, volume, sphere, temp, density, pound, ounce, ton, gram,".contains(convert)) {
            StringBuffer.append(convert);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Addressing the comments:

> why `if(convert.contains("...."))` doesn't works ?

The easiest way is to have a look at [the documentation of `String.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)): *Returns true if and only if **this string** contains **the specified sequence of char values**.*

**this string** in the original example from the question(*not in my answer*) is `convert`, which can be either `"mass"` or `"volume"` or etc.;

**the specified sequence of char values** is that long string `"mass, volume, ..."`.

So, how e.g. `"mass"` can contain `"mass, volume, etc."`? It is the other way around indeed: `"mass, volume, etc.".contains("mass") == true`

> HashSet.contains would be more performant

It doesn't look like the strings will be large enough to feel a performance increase in this example, but generally speaking it's a good point especially if the number of possible inputs is not small and for readability and maintainability. You can have it like this:

```
// This part may vary:
private static String [] variants = {"mass", "volume", "sphere", "temp", "density", "pound", "ounce", "ton", "gram"};
private static Set<String> inputs = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(variants));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        StringBuffer StringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi, what are you trying to find?");
        System.out.println("mass");
        System.out.println("vol");
        System.out.println("temp");
        System.out.println("sphere");
        System.out.println("density");
        String convert = input.nextLine();
        if (inputs.contains(convert)) {
            StringBuffer.append(convert);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Probably not in this example. The string is too short.

Comment: linear search is worse in every way possible compared to the `O(1)` complexity of looking in hash buckets (aside for code length, which is not a gain), and for that reason `HashSet` is almost a natural fit for this use case. Unfortunately, this looks like a homework problem, and using tools provided by the standard library would probably not be preferable in the teacher's eyes. @cricket_007

Comment: @zhelezoglo +1 for explanation.